# Insanity: IF clause breaks LOCATION clause

Tags: nginx

With `nginx.conf` including the following

```
     location /beta/ {
        proxy_pass http://otherhost/;
      }
```

then both of the following retrievals work:

- `curl -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla' http://localhost/beta/admin.html`
- `curl -H 'User-Agent: iPhone' http://localhost/beta/admin.html`

They both retrieve `http://otherhost/admin.html`

When I change nginx.conf to read:

```
     location /beta/ {
        if ($http_user_agent ~ iPhone ) {
        }
        proxy_pass http://otherhost/;
      }
```

Then `curl -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla' http://localhost/beta/admin.html` continues to work but 
`curl -H 'User-Agent: iPhone' http://localhost/beta/admin.html` gives a 404 and otherhost complains that it doesn't have a file called `beta/admin.html`.  This happens whether `if` is empty or not.

Huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting bit by a known problem: [If is evil in nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil), meaning avoid `if`-blocks inside `location`-blocks if at all posible (the link explains why and how)