# Nginx proxy or rewrite depending on user agent, without if

Tags: nginx

I need to serve different files depending on the user-agent.  This is an extraordinarily basic requirement, one step up from serving files at all.

The [standard answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627596/nginx-proxy-or-rewrite-depending-on-user-agent) seems to be, use an `if` statement.

However, it is apparently well-known that [`if` statements shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745134/238884).

So the answer at this moment seems to be Apache, but I told my boss nginx was a usable product.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you read [if is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) carefully you'll notice it has the following quote:

```
The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in location context are:
return ...;
rewrite ... last; 

Anything else may possibly cause unpredictable behaviour, including potential
SIGSEGV.
```

So...

the evilness of `if` is only applicable to use within a location block

inside a `location`-block there are two, and only two, guaranteed save uses of an `if` block:

- one holding a lone `return ...;` statement
- one holding a lone `rewrite ... last;` statement
- (note that an empty `if` block can lead to problems also)

non-guaranteed save uses of `if` in a location block *may* work, but need to be tested

Comment: That's actually where I started.  I couldn't get the lone `rewrite` to work.  Actually, I don't know if I tried the combination of 1 rewrite and the `last` keyword.  The page hinted that nginx will be ready for commercial use with the next release.

Comment: http://news.netcraft.com/ seems to indicate that nginx currently has a 12,64% webserver marketshare, and that's been rising consistenly for a while now. In other words, depending on what you're doing it already is, YMMV naturally